# Why is the 'iptables' target 'NFLOG" not sending log messages to the Kernel?

Tags: kernel, logging, iptables

I recently started using an old cell phone, Samsung Galaxy J7 model SM-J700M. I rooted it, flashed LineageOS and installed a SIM card and it works just fine. I decided to work on a script with iptables rules, run it and noticed there are a few problems. The 'iptables' target 'LOG' gives an error message when used, then I use 'NFLOG' but it doesn't send any log messages to the kernel when packets traverse it. I thought maybe some modules are not loaded.

I used the command 'lsmod':

```
j7elte:/ # lsmod
lsmod: No file /proc/modules: No such file or directory
1|j7elte:/ #
```

Then I played around with 'modprobe':

```
j7elte:/ # modprobe -a <module_name>                                                                                                         
modprobe: No file /proc/modules: No such file or directory
1|j7elte:/ #
```

What I can tell is, that the kernel is missing a whole lot of things. I was never good with the Android or the kernel.

How can I get the 'iptables' target 'NFLOG' to send messages to the kernel so that they appear after using 'dmesg' or 'adb logcat'?

Here is a snippit of 'logcat':

```
02-14 01:17:00.937  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:00.937  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:01.242  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:01.251  5245  5245 W sh      : type=1400 audit(0.0:906): avc: denied { read } for name="mediaserver" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=704 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mediaserver_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
02-14 01:17:01.251  5245  5245 W sh      : type=1300 audit(0.0:906): arch=40000028 syscall=334 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=e7723060 a2=4 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2437 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) exe="/system/bin/sh" subj=u:r:shell:s0 key=(null)
02-14 01:17:01.251  2298  2298 W auditd  : type=1327 audit(0.0:906): proctitle=2F73797374656D2F62696E2F7368002D63006578706F727420414E44524F49445F4C4F475F544147533D222727223B2065786563206C6F67636174
02-14 01:17:01.251  2298  2298 W auditd  : type=1320 audit(0.0:906):
02-14 01:17:01.291  5245  5245 W logcat  : type=1400 audit(0.0:907): avc: denied { read } for name="mediaserver" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=704 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mediaserver_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
02-14 01:17:01.291  5245  5245 W logcat  : type=1300 audit(0.0:907): arch=40000028 syscall=334 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=f77230a0 a2=4 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2437 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) exe="/system/bin/logcat" subj=u:r:shell:s0 key=(null)
02-14 01:17:01.938  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:01.938  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:02.244  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:02.939  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:02.940  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:03.247  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:03.941  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:03.941  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:04.249  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:04.291  2400  2400 W health@2.0-serv: type=1400 audit(0.0:908): avc: denied { read } for name="type" dev="sysfs" ino=12556 scontext=u:r:hal_health_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
02-14 01:17:04.291  2400  2400 W health@2.0-serv: type=1300 audit(0.0:908): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=f6b11360 a2=a8000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) exe="/system/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.health@2.0-service" subj=u:r:hal_health_default:s0 key=(null)
02-14 01:17:04.291  2298  2298 W auditd  : type=1327 audit(0.0:908): proctitle="/vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.health@2.0-service"
02-14 01:17:04.291  2298  2298 W auditd  : type=1320 audit(0.0:908):
02-14 01:17:04.324  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:04.325  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:04.650  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:04.941  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:04.942  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:05.252  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:05.944  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:05.944  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:06.254  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:06.944  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:06.945  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:07.256  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:07.945  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:07.945  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:08.259  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:08.947  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:08.947  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:09.261  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:09.948  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:09.948  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:10.264  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:10.966  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:10.966  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
02-14 01:17:11.266  2417  4576 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(3)
02-14 01:17:11.967  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] first frame after HWC_2_GLES
02-14 01:17:11.967  2417  2417 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] GLES_2_HWC by high FPS(5)
```

Comment: `NFLOG` target doesn't write to kernel log but broadcasts to Netlink sockets.